# Advancing slides on Mousewheel event

Tags: slider

I would like to understand how to trigger the nextslide() function in the Revolution Slider API from a Jquery block on a wordpress page. I have a slide show with six slides ... in addition to being able to advance them with the nav buttons, I'd like to be able to have the mouse wheel also advance my slides.

I gather I need to do this using the API functions, but haven't been able to find any examples online of binding the nextslide() function to a mousewheel event. Thank you.

I found this article on the Revolution API, but it's too different from what I'm trying to do to be helpful.

http://www.themepunch.com/home/plugins/wordpress-plugins/revolution-slider-wordpress/api-example-pauseresume-the-slider-on-page-scroll/

Comment: I may be able to just use the scroll event. This would save me using a plugin. All I need is to advance to the next slide when an attempt to scroll has been made ... whether this includes a mousewheel scroll, I do not know ... but here is the code I tried. You can see what I'm attempting ... may need that mousewheel event after all ...

.. to be continued ...

Comment: $(function(){
    var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var _direction;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(_top < _cur_top)
        {
            revapi17.revnext();;
        }
        else
        {
            revapi17.revprev();;
        }
        _top = _cur_top;
        console.log(_direction);
    });
});

});

Comment: This way technically works, but it has the potential to scroll through the entire deck of slides of you really spin the mousewheel. How would I get it to only advance one slide after each mousewheel scroll?

http://devonline.wpengine.com/story-2/